# Sending geolocation through php to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, actionscript-3, geolocation

I am trying to send geolocation data from an android device through php to mysql. For some reason it does not work. It does not show up in the mySQL database. Am I doing something wrong?

AS3

```
var myLat;
var myLong;
if (Geolocation.isSupported){
    var my_geo:Geolocation = new Geolocation();
    my_geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onGeoUpdate);
    my_geo.setRequestedUpdateInterval(100);
} 
function onGeoUpdate(event:GeolocationEvent):void {
    myLat = event.latitude;
    myLong = event.longitude;
    test1.text = myLat;
    test2.text = myLong;
}
// Send Geolocation
function sendGps():void {
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.mypage.com/handler.php");
    varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    varSend.data = variables;
    var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
    varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    variables.myrequest = "write_gps";
    variables.username = userName;
    variables.lati = myLat;
    variables.longi = myLong;
    varLoader.load(varSend);    
}

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runItAll);
myTimer.start();
function runItAll(event:TimerEvent):void {
     sendGps();
}
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['myrequest']) && $_POST['myrequest'] == "write_gps") {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $latitude = $_POST['lati'];
    $longitude = $_POST['longi'];
    require_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
    $update_sql = mysql_query("UPDATE current SET longitude='$longitude',     latitude='$latitude' WHERE username='$username'");
    mysql_close();
};
```

Comment: What if it is simply has the wrong datatype in the database? Tr to make longitude and latitude columns of datatype `VARCHAR` and check again.

Comment: Yeah, it's all set. Even tried TEXT as as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is open for a SQL Injection and you should always use PDO(http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.php) when interacting with MySQL.

Are you getting the data you need when you do a print_r($_POST) in the PHP code?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!
I tried, and it seems the data is not getting through from AS3 to PHP. I am wondering if it has something to do with how the geolocation code is structured...

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 part of your code `varLoader` isn't protected from garbage collector, it can lead to issue when `URLLoader` don't send any data. To prevent `varLoader` from GC you can add `Event.COMPLETE` listener without weak reference:

```
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete)

private function onLoaderComplete(event:Event):void
{
    URLLoader(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type, onLoaderComplete);
}
```

I also recommend you use `URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES` instead of `URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT` since you send URL encoded params.